# QWebEngine. How to get complete page HTML together with frames

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

Is there a way to get HTML content of the page together with iframes? I tried [QWebEnginePage::toHtml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#toHtml) but it returns HTML of main frame only. I need HTML of whole page together with all child frames.

QWebEngine (unlike QWebKit) doesn't have API to access frames, this could be done only via page content using javascript. However javascript also doesn't allow to access child frames from another domain/scheme.

Comment: You could explain me better, it would help if you would show what you want to get.

Comment: I need HTML content of all frames, not only main frame. Current version of toHtml API method returns only main frame. I need to find the way to get all other frames HTML as well.